# FullCalendarBundle handle event error in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar

I installed fullcalendarbundle, and I configured it as it is mentioned on the Github
https://github.com/tattali/CalendarBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/doc/doctrine-crud.md#3-create-the-crud, I can display the calendar. But when I try to create calendar event. I have error

```
The "AppBundle\Repository\CalendarEventsRepository" entity repository implements "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface", but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".
```

Here is my repository

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;
use AppBundle\Entity\CalendarEvents;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
class CalendarEventsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CalendarEvents::class);
    }
}
```

My services.yml configured like this.

```
parameters:
services:
  #default configuration for services in *this* file

    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


   # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
   #   arguments:
   #          $someArgument: 'some_value'
   #   AppBundle\Twig\PlanningExtension:
   #         tags: ['twig.extension']
   # adding the required tag to all repository services

   #AppBundle\Repository\CalendarEventsRepository:
   #   arguments:
   #      - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
   #      - '@=service("doctrine.orm.entity_manager").getClassMetadata("AppBundle\\Entity\\CalendarEvents")'
   #   tags:
        # - { name: doctrine.repository_service }
```

I'm on symfony 3.4. I looked for several solutions without success, if you have a solution. I will be glad you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to autowire repositories, modify the exclude setting:

```
AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
```

...defines: autowire everything in `src/AppBundle`, except those classes in the subfolders `Entity`, `Repository`, and `Tests`. By removing `Repository` from that list, you allow autowiring for your repositories

Comment: Nico, thanks a lot for your answer. this error is corrected. But I still don't have what I want, my goal is to display the events in the calendar. I have the impression that it does not detect my CalendarSubscriber file, reason why even if I make errors they do not report anything.

Comment: Please open a new question for this, containing all relevant information